# operator precedence in C programming language

Tags: c

If I write the code like this below?

```
int arr[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int *ptr = arr;
*(ptr++)+= 123;
```

what's the elements in the arr[] now?

I originally thougt the arr[] now should be {6, 130, 8, 9, 10}, but actully the result is {129, 7, 8, 9, 10}, I don't know why?

In my opinion, ptr++ is in the bracket, so the ptr should increase first, isn't it? after it increased one, it should point to the second element in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **value of `ptr++`** is the value of `ptr` before any increment (*the side-effect is incrementing `ptr` at some time during the evaluation of the expression*).

That is the value that is dereferenced in `*(ptr++)`.

*If you dereference `ptr` in a subsequent expression, it points to the next element, the one with value `7`.*

Answer (score 4):

Use `++ptr` (i.e. pre-increment) if you want the behaviour you're expecting.  Parentheses don't affect *when* the post-increment occurs.  In other words, it's nothing to do with precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The basic meaning of **ptr++** is **First use then Increment** that is why it is know as **Post Increment Operator**. It means that the value of the variable ptr will be updated only when the current instruction has finished execution and the variable is used again in subsequent instructions.

While just the opposite applies for **++ptr** is **First Increment then use** and it is known as **Pre Increment Operator**.

Comment: That's a simplified way of looking at it. `ptr++` has a value (the original value of `ptr`) and a side-effect (increment). When the side-effect occurs in relation to when the value is used is not specified by the language.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of this ptr++ will take place only after ';'
ptr++  is equivalent to ptr = ptr + 1; but this will done only
after semicolon of that statement.
ptr value will be arr[0] during the operation *(ptr++)+= 123;
but after that statement ptr will be equivalent to arr[1]

Comment: If you check the selected and **correct** answer, it says *"the side-effect is incrementing `ptr` at some time during the evaluation of the expression)"*. Note "during", not "after".